# Why would a Rails application explicitly declare config.gem 'rails' in environment.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rubygems

A sample application I was looking at has this in `environment.rb`:

```
  config.gem 'rails'
```

Is this redundant code or is there likely to be a reason the programmer did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's redundant code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use that if you had multiple versions of the Rails gem, and didn't freeze Rails into your application, so you could do something like

```
config.gem 'rails', :version => 2.2.2
```

But otherwise, it's redundant.

Comment: Even that's redundant, thanks to the `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION` a few lines earlier in the same file.

Comment: Agreed. I just don't know why config.gem 'rails' would ever show up.